# Why are my post not formatted correctly in the category menu, but the post preview is fine?

Tags: wordpress, formatting, blogs

here are both the links 
post preview link: https://testfellow.com/2018/10/04/test-post/

here is the category menu link with the same post : 
https://testfellow.com/category/ms-office-mcqs/
please help

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the two are rendered in different template code.